# Getting the file kind by extension on iOS

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsfilemanager

When I take a `.dae` file and do `File, Info` on OSX's finder I see

```
Kind: Digital Asset Exchange (DAE)
```

`.rtfd` shows

```
Kind: Rich Text Document with Attachments
```

But this is OSX. Now, how do I discover the kind of file on iOS by the NSURL of that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be other ways, but one way is to use the uniform type identifier (UTI) services provided by `MobileCoreServices`.

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

Just get the description associated with the extension's UTI:

```
if let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, pathExtension, nil)?.takeRetainedValue(), let description = UTTypeCopyDescription(uti)?.takeRetainedValue() {
    print(description)
}
```

See the [How the System Identifies the Type of Content in a File](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW16) in the *File System Programming Guide.*

Comment: Nope. That shows me `org.khronos.collada.digital.asset.exchange` for `dae` files and `dyn.age8402k` for files it cannot identify. I think it is almost there but not yet.

Comment: First, the `org.khronos...` is the UTI. If you then get the description for that UTI with `UTTypeCopyDescription`, like shown above, I get a description of "Digital Asset Exchange (DAE)". Second, for the extension `age8402k`, what did you expect it to show? That doesn't sound like an extension for which a UTI would have been registered on the device. Also, remember, you might have UTI's registered on your Mac OS that might not be registered on iOS, so don't confuse the two.

Comment: you are right. I had a bug on my system calling the wrong method. It is now showing the correct description. THANKS, you are awesome!